# Can i call java runnable jar using using Informatica java transformation directly with input and output parameters.?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I want to call this runnable jar with input and output parameters using function or in java expression in java transformation:

```
java -classpath a.jar:b.jar \
     -Xms128m \
     -Xmx1024m {main class} \
     -i ${FILE_IN} \
     -o ${FILE_OUT}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

i think you can but not the way you are thinking. You can put the third party jar file in infa lib folder and then import the program in java transformation. If that is a possibility then i think you can follow below steps.

1. Place Jar file in  /infahome/Informatica8/server/bin/javalib/. Place same jar file in Infa client too and list it in JTX properties.
2. Set the class path in processes in IS
3. Restart infa.
4. Write Code in java transformation and compile.
   [image]

Comment: try
{
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -classpath a.jar:b.jar
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m {main class}
-i ${FILE_IN}
-o ${FILE_OUT}");

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (process.getInputStream()));
    String line;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
output.append(line + "\n");
}
}


catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}